Apex Form with multiple IG's
I have a basic form that I'm tring to build with multiple interactive grids that I cant seem to get working.
Here is a breakdown of the form, I have 4 sections which 3 of them I would like to be IG's as the user has to enter multple values.
Section 1 is the location information.

Section 2 is the first IG.

Section 3 is the second IG.

And I will probally have another 2 IG's later.
I thought that I could use one table for this form.
An Example if a user fills out the Location information then section 2 and 3 which could have multiple entries, which all works fine but the location information is not duplicated to sections 2 & 3.
See yellow below:

Thanks for any help.

One table? Certainly, you could, but you should not. Normalize data model and

keep location info in one table (which has a primary key)
put products into a separate table (which has a foreign key, referencing primary key of the location table)

RE and TU tables (screenshots you posted) are similar (TU doesn't have the "Type" column), but that can be kept in the same table with additional column that distinguishes RE rows from TU rows.

if there are only two types, use a check constraint; if you expect more row types, create a separate table and join it with product via foreign key constraint





Something like this:
create table location 
  (loc_id     number primary key,
   loc_name   varchar2(20) not null,
   loc_number number,
   ...
  );

create table product
  (prod_id   number primary key,
   loc_id    number      constraint fk_prod_loc references location (loc_id),
   row_type  varchar2(2) constraint ch_rowtype check (row_type in ('RE', 'TU'),
   serial    number not null,
   ...
  );

